# PlayFramework Attempted to serialize java.lang.Class

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, gson

I am trying to integrate gson in my Play! 2.x. I am using gson & jongo and facing this error : http://hastebin.com/agewopocen.bash

Here is my model class:

```
public class Person extends MongoModel<Person>
{

    ObjectId _id;
    String name;
    int age;

    public Person()
    {
        super(Person.class, "person");
    }

    public Person(String name, int age)
    {
        super(Person.class, "person");
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        System.out.println();
    }

    @Override
    public Person setModel()
    {
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectId getId()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public int getAge()
    {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age)
    {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String toJson()
    {
        return new GsonBuilder().create().toJson(this);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return new Gson().toJson(this);
    }
}
```

I don't know what a "TypeAdapter" is (mentioned in the error log in the above link) and I am sure that we can get this working without using it. But, I dont know what I am missing.

Here is the code I tried (without Play, in regular Java) and it works.

```
public class Test
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Person nfe = new Person(10, "nfe");
        String s = new Gson().toJson(nfe);
        System.out.println(s);
    }

    public static class Person {
        int age;
        String name;

        public Person(int age, String name)
        {
            this.age = age;
            this.name = name;
        }


        public int getAge()
        {
            return age;
        }

        public void setAge(int age)
        {
            this.age = age;
        }

        public void setName(String name)
        {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
}
```

Output :

```
{"age":10,"name":"nfe"}
```

Can someone help me in fixing this?

Comment: The default json serializer for Play! is Jackson. There is an inbuilt parser in Play. Use this

       "import play.libs.Json;"

       "Json.toJson()"

I dont have any idea right now why it says so, but switch to this and check

Comment: I always use the gson ! But thank's you for your awnser !

Comment: I cant use Jackson because i've Direct self-reference ... I won't use multiple class. My architecture is fine now. But i can't serialize in json my class !